# jQuery has detected parents incorrectly

Tags: jquery

I have html structure like below:

```
<div id="banner-menu-holder">
    <div>
        <div class="avalible">
            <div class="items-holder">
                <div>
                    <div class="img-holder">
                        <div>
                            <input id="set_banner_29" type="checkbox" onclick="mod.setBanner(29);">
                            ...
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ready">
            <div class="items-holder">
                <div>
                    <div class="img-holder">
                        <div>
                            <input id="rem_banner_1_8_32" class="remove_banner" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
                            ...
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and js code:

```
$(document).click(function(ev) {
    if ($(ev.target).parents().index($('#banner-menu-holder')) == -1) {
        $('#banner-menu-holder').css('display', 'none');
    }        
})
```

When I clicked checkbox into first div (class avalible) then function has been successfull executed - this chekbox is child of main div (#banner-menu-holder).

When I clicked second div's checkboxes and the function had not worked. jQuery didn't detected that these checkboxes are children of main div.

Is that problem into jQuery or otherwise?

Comment: What makes you think the function is not executed? Since they both descend from `#banner-menu-holder`, the `.index()` will not return `-1`, so nothing should happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're doing event delegation, but in a very clunky way.

jQuery makes this easier with `.on()`.

```
$(document).on('click', '#banner-menu-holder', function(ev) {
    $('#banner-menu-holder').css('display', 'none');
});
$(document).on('click', ':not(#banner-menu-holder)', function(ev) {
    $('#banner-menu-holder').css('display', 'none');
});
```

---

If you're using jQuery 1.4-1.6.x, you'd use `.delegate()` instead.

```
$(document).delegate('#banner-menu-holder', 'click', function(ev) {
    $('#banner-menu-holder').css('display', 'none');
});

$(document).delegate(':not(#banner-menu-holder)', 'click', function(ev) {
    // do something else
});
```

Comment: As I understood you I should bind click on .remove_banner but I have checkboxes without that class too. When bind onClick to it by #banner-menu-holder div it had worked incorrectly.

Comment: And I forgot to mention that after function IF I have the ELSE that should be executed if current element have not parent #banner-menu-holder (all another elements into page). Sorry for my English.

Comment: So you're saying that a click anywhere inside the banner should hide the banner? If so, just remove the `.remove_banner` part of the selectors in my answer.

Comment: Yes, you are right! But there is a little problem - for click anywhere outside the banner there should be function where checking the parents is incorrectly - we will get some elements from the banner too.

Comment: @diNord: I updated my answer to add a second handler that uses the `:not()` selector. `':not(#banner-menu-holder)'` This should handle all clicks outside the banner,.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to check if the current element has a parent with the `banner-menu-holder` id:

```
if (!$(ev.target).closest('#banner-menu-holder').length) {
    $('#banner-menu-holder').css('display', 'none');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but if you are trying to see if the clicked element is inside the `#banner-menu-holder` element I would write it like this:

```
if($(ev.target).closest('#banner-menu-holder').length > 0) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I have trying your code right now and have got an interesting thing - checkboxes into the first div had not worked but into the second div all is ok. They are swapped!